# Get extension from an email address

Tags: php, email

I have a list of email and I would like to find a simple php code or regex to isolate the extension only so I can have an idea about where members come from.
For example if his email is name@compagny.fr, I'd like to isolate ".fr"
Is there a simple way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, you might want to take the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) again or read [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) once or twice..

Comment: try: echo end(explode('.','name@compagny.fr'));

Comment: @DharaParmar thats not good enough. `john.doe@google.com` for example.

Comment: @DharaParmar: Not that simple or I would not have asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Echo strrev(Explode(".", Strrev($email))[0]);
```

Strrev flips the backwards so explode explodes on the last dot.
Not tested though

Edit: since both me and dimlucas had the same idea I will add another solution:

```
Echo preg_match("/\.(\w+)$/", $email)[1];
```

Comment: Perfect, I have just tested, I didn't know the strrev function. Very useful. Thank you so much

Comment: @sim100 no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that the email is stored in a variable called `$email` you can start by reversing the email using `strrev`.

```
$reverse = strrev($email)
```

You can then use `explode` to get an array that will always hold the country code on index 0:

```
$contents = explode('.', $reverse);
```

You obviously need to reverse the string because a country code of, say, '.fr' will be stored as '.rf'

```
$countryCode = strrev($contents[0]);
```

Note that you don't need to reverse anything if you're absolutely certain that there will be no '.' symbols in the email address other than the one before the extension. In that case you can just explode the string and get the last value

Comment: Similar than Andreas solution. I didn't know the strrev function and I am glad to know it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You get an upvote from me since we had the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Most elegant way is to missuse pathinfo.

```
$email = 'test@domain.co.uk';

$extention = pathinfo($email, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

gives back 'uk'
```